# Colocar el valor de una columna en otra columna de filas diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Necesito crear un select donde se coloque en valor de una columna en otra columna los cuales pertenecen a filas diferentes, utilizando el criterio de la columna tipo.

En otras palabras, colocar el valor de columna_uno en la columna_dos cuando tipo sea = 'B'.
Tipo'C' no se debe colocar en columna_dos.
Por Ejemplo

```
id  descripción  tipo    columna_uno    columna_dos
1   grain          A     1000   
2   beans          B                    1000 (valor perteneciente a la columna_uno)
3   sugar          C     2000
```

Estoy intentando algo como esto pero no obtengo el resultado deseado

```
 SELECT id, decripcion, tipo, columna_uno, 
     CASE WHEN tipo = 'B' THEN columna_uno end columna_dos
```

Es posible hacer esto y cómo sería?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Esto `SELECT id, decripcion, tipo, columna_uno,CASE WHEN tipo = 'B' THEN columna_uno ELSE NULL end columna_dos` tal vez?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, decripcion, tipo, 
CASE WHEN tipo != 'B' THEN columna_uno ELSE NULL end columna_uno ,
CASE WHEN tipo = 'B' THEN columna_uno ELSE NULL end columna_dos from nametable;
```

según entiendo seria algo asi

Answer (score 0):

Explicando mejor la respuesta seria algo así:

```
SELECT id, descripcion,tipo,
CASE tipo
WHEN "B" THEN columna_uno 
WHEN "C" THEN columna_dos
END as tipo_columna

FROM nametable
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.